# How to get the name of a channel and role from an id in a discord bot python

Tags: discord, discord.py

I have the id of roles but I need to find a way to get their names. I have tried using `ctx.guild.get_role("roleid").name` but it seems that it dose not give the good datatype. The same goes for text channels and users.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use [`discord.utils.get`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=discord%20utils%20get#discord.utils.get):

```py
from discord.ext import commands
from discord.utils import get

def getter(iterables, id: int):
    data = get(iterables, id=id)
    return data

@bot.command()
async def display_data(ctx):
    #Get roles
    role = getter(ctx.guild.roles, id)
    #Get channels
    channel = getter(ctx.guild.channels, id)
    #Get users
    user = getter(ctx.guild.members, id)

    await ctx.send(f"Data found:\nRole:{role.name}\nChannel:{channel.name}\nUser:{user.name}")
```

**Data types:**

- User → [`Member`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=member#discord.Member) object
- Role → [`Role`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=role#discord.Role) object
- Channel → [`TextChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.TextChannel) or [`VoiceChannel`](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html?highlight=channel#discord.VoiceChannel) object

**Reference:** [discord.py documentation](https://discordpy.readthedocs.io/en/latest/)